# Python binding for VlC - error in displaying video title

Tags: python, streaming, vlc

I am trying to stream network links on vlc using python.

my code is :

```
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new_location(url)
player.set_media(Media)
player.set_title(1)
player.set_video_title_display(6,5000)
player.play()
```

I keep getting an error related to Cfuntcion

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases item 2 in _argtypes_ has no from_param method
```

any ideas how to fix it? or how i can display whatever title I require on the player?

Answer (score 0):

There's `setWindowTitle()` method, in PyQt4 using this, you can have title as per your requirement;
Click [here](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob_plain;f=examples/qtvlc.py;hb=HEAD) ,see this simple example vlc example(provided by vlc wiki)

Other examples can be seen from [here](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=examples;hb=HEAD) !